# CloudWatch log group not filtering pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch log group that is set to look for a specific pattern (a domain name) to be used as a trigger for a lambda function, but every time I perform a lookup on the domain, it doesn't show up in the logs.

I am a complete newbie to this and it is my first time doing it, so I apologize for the lack of information. Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide with.

I created a lambda subscription filter with the pattern to be the domain name.

Comment: Can you see an event in the log that you expect to match the domain name pattern? Can you find a result when you type the domain name into the search in the console?

Comment: I do not. I created a log event with the pattern and the lambda function got triggered perfectly fine. The problem is that it isn't logging anything.

Comment: Can you share the subscription filter you have set up?

Comment: _"I created a log event with the pattern and the lambda function got triggered"_. So you can write a sample event to the log group, which triggers your Lambda?

_"It isn't logging anything"_. Do you mean that, apart from your sample events, the source log group never receives the events that the Lambda is supposed to process?

_"Every time I perform a lookup on the domain, it doesn't show up in the logs"_. What does "lookup" mean here? Does the log group contain Route 53 DNS query logs?

Comment: As @Cloudlady says, can you share more information about your set up? Even just some screenshots of the console that show your resources' configuration would help. If you configured the resources using CloudFormation, Terraform, or a script, can ytou share the relevant parts?